# JSON beginner - when to use JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json

When I want to exchange data between client and server, I did not use JSON.
If I send data from PHP to Javascript,  I do it like this...

```
<script>
var foo = <?php echo $phpfoo; ?>;
</script>
```

and If I want to send data from javascript to PHP, I will use AJAX.

So I don't know When to use JSON?  or it only be use in only API, Web Service?

Comment: JSON is a way to format the data being transferred, in your case between JS to PHP using an Ajax Request. This way you can send objects in a string.

Comment: json is made for big data constructs. you can simply create an array or an object in php, than convert it to json, wich is equivalent to the javascript syntax. So you dont need to encode the objects/arrays yourself

Answer (score 2):

JSON is very useful when you want to share variables and data between two different languages in general (not only php and js). And if you are using AJAX chances are that you already are using JSON. For an example if you would use an AJAX command like bellow it will be using JSON:

```
$.post("someFile.php",
    {
        // This is JSON
        variable1: "value",
        variable2: "nextValue"
    },
    function (data, status) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
```

This can be used to transfer everything from common variables to arrays